# Sounds that have never been recorded before.

Tags: recording

I thought maybe we could make a list of sounds that occur which have never been recorded before to our knowledge.

So, if you were given a golden ticket, good for one isolated recording of anything you could think of no matter how difficult it would be to capture it, what would it be?

Answer (score 3):

The sound of a heart breaking! lol

Comment: or coming back together?

Comment: "The sound of a heart breaking" is actually called for in the script for the play "Kid Simple," which I designed last fall. Specifically, the stage direction says "sound of something pulled up by the roots," and a character says "it's the sound of a broken heart."


Answer (score 2):

That's a bloody tough one.  I can think of a multitude of things that I personally haven't recorded, and would love to, but I'm having a really hard time thinking of anything that hasn't been recorded.

Answer (score 2):

God? Perhaps a Martian sandstorm -- someone should stick a M/S mic on the next rover. Also, Creatures that died out before the late 19th century.

Answer (score 2):

The tree that falls in the forest when there's no one there to see it fall?

Comment: I thought about adding this.  

This Is Your Brain On Music answered the age-old question, too: the answer is no, since sound is just an interpretation of vibrations in the air by your brain, using your ear essentially as the interface.  As soon as you add something that can interpret the vibrations, you get sound.

Comment: @Dave Matney LOL, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

The sound of silence!

Comment: Oh wait, simon and garfunkle already covered that one

Comment: And it's surprisingly not silent.  Hmm... perhaps they got it wrong?

Comment: John Cage did 4'33 of it....

Answer (score 2):

Solar flares....

Comment: see the video for this month's challenge on my website. solar flares actually cause natural radio phenomenon that gets recorded all the time.

Comment: I did! I do look at it as Earth's atmosphere reacting to the particles though. No substitute for solar flares think ;) just a majestic dream for now, i suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Capture some squirrels making noise or actually barking. I was taking out the trash when I used to live in a Long Island suburb when some squirrels were running around the tree branches above me. They looked adorable until I heard one of them make this grotesque sounding bark. It totally kills their image, imho. They should remain silent!

Comment: i know what you're talking about...demented little buggers aren't they?!

Answer (score 2):

the music in my head exactly recorded.

Answer (score 1):

Has an active volcano ever been recorded? I imagine you could have a good recording session going there with MS, contact mics, omnis...

Comment: and sacrificial radio mics, for when you have to get the hell out of there.... but want to keep recording... "move further away, i can still hear our helicopter..."

Comment: Isn't there a show called Lava Hunter or something where this old photographer for Nat Geo goes to all these active volcanos, so their sound recordist probably got some stuff recorded there hopefully lol, here's a cool picture that photographer got in the 70s http://bit.ly/h1yfCO

Answer (score 1):

my only suggestion would involve time travel, so probably not very realistic... no golden ticket could make that happen

Answer (score 1):

Has anyone ever got a hydrophone into someones stomach to record those weird stomach growls? I guess that could be cool, unless those cameras doctors use have mics on them.

Comment: A guy I went to film school with once swallowed a Sanken cos-11 mic to record stomach sounds.

Comment: Wow, how did it sound in there?

Comment: On of the sound editors for Star Trek the Next Generation (Wolvington I think) did something similar to that for the sound of the interior of a spaceship that was supposed to be a "living thing"

Answer (score 1):

Lunar footsteps. You would probably have to use contact mics due to the lack of atmosphere...

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that many things are recorded for scientific purposes as opposed to sound design.

I'm pretty sure that if it's been experienced, then it's been recorded. If not to tape or hard drive, then to our hearts and minds.

Comment: I also considered this... how many things out there haven't been recorded in high fidelity, but have been recorded by camera mics, dictaphones, and other low-quality mics?

Answer (score 1):

The sound of HAARP as it shoots ions into the sky.

Answer (score 1):

I want to hear what it sounds like in my stomach as I digest some red hot chili.

Anyone have a acid proof lav?

...This is actually a pretty good idea... I might try this...

Comment: lol these aren't the types of answers I was expecting when I asked this question but it's fun anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The sound of someones brain during an adrenaline rush.

Answer (score 0):

There are some unexplained sounds that many people have experienced, but nobody's managed to record. [The Bristol Hum](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-35344544) is my local one, a low tone that can be heard on quiet nights in the south of the city.

Probably not a particularly interesting recording, actually. If the Golden Ticket is magical, can I have some dinosaur calls, please?